# get sklearn fit stdout in a logfile

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn GridSearchCV(SomeModel, SomeTunedParams, SomeScoring ,verbose=10)

I need to get all output generated by verbose in a file, especially this kind of rows :

```
[CV]  n_estimators=50, max_depth=8, class_weight=subsample, score=0.944444 -   0.3s
```

In fact it's a more general question related to sklearn fit method.

The goal is to put this stdout into a logfile.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing all output from sklearn GridSearchCV to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787220/printing-all-output-from-sklearn-gridsearchcv-to-file)