# Printing all output from sklearn GridSearchCV to file?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am running a long grid-search using `sklearn` and I want to log *all* (emphasis **all**) console output to file. **Running from terminal using `>` and changing stdout to an open file etc. all work ... but only partially** which is the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728). Anything called by `print` does get saved to file, but **not** *everything* shown on console is saved. In particular for:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 128 candidates, totalling 640 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  42 tasks      | elapsed:    2.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done 192 tasks      | elapsed:   12.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done 442 tasks      | elapsed:   35.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done 640 out of 640 | elapsed:   55.7s finished
```

the first line does get saved to file. But the logging from `[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]` is not saved. Instead:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 128 candidates, totalling 640 fits
{'estimator__max_depth': 5, 'estimator__min_samples_leaf': 4, 'estimator__min_samples_split': 8}
...
...
```

The second line is me simply printing best parameters obtained; everything from `[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]` is lost. Does anyone know how to make this get saved to file also?

Comment: You can try [re-directing the stdout from python to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/3374996).

Comment: I tried and the question mentions that it does not work.

Comment: Only the lines containing `[Parallel(n_jobs=4)...]` will be skipped if you followed that answer. That can be overcome by also redirecting the `sys.stderr` to the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [source](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0bc239b84ff2bfd441e81ea33c781ba2e42a2525/joblib/parallel.py) of the `joblib` package used internally by `sklearn` for parallelization:

```
def _print(self, msg, msg_args):
    """Display the message on stout or stderr depending on verbosity"""
    # XXX: Not using the logger framework: need to
    # learn to use logger better.
    if not self.verbose:
        return
    if self.verbose < 50:
        writer = sys.stderr.write
    else:
        writer = sys.stdout.write
    msg = msg % msg_args
    writer('[%s]: %s\n' % (self, msg))
```

So with `verbose=1` as the OP was using, redirecting `stderr` ought to capture the missing lines. But then this will not get `stdout`. So one can just merge them using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325249/6395452) and doing:

```
# necessary imports

logfile = open('test.txt', 'w')

original_stderr = sys.stderr
original_stdout = sys.stdout

sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, logfile)
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
.
.
[code to log]
.
.

sys.stdout = original_stdout
sys.stderr = original_stderr
logfile.close()
```