# redirect GridSearchCV (or any other Sklearn object) output to file

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, console-output

I want to be able to save GridSearchCV output to file **while running**.

```
GridSearchCV(XGBClassifier(), tuned_parameters, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
```

This is an example for an output:

```
    Fitting 1 folds for each of 200 candidates, totalling 200 fits
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend with 4 concurrent workers.
    [CV] colsample_bytree=0.7, learning_rate=0.05, max_depth=4, n_estimators=300, subsample=0.7  
    [CV] colsample_bytree=0.7, learning_rate=0.05, max_depth=4, n_estimators=300, subsample=0.7 
score=0.645, total= 6.3min
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:  6.3min
```

I managed to save the first line and the Parallel lines, **but no matter what I tried, I couldn't save the lines that start with [CV]**.
I want to save those lines so if the program will fail, I could at least see part of the results.

I tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/22434262#22434262)

```
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
```

and:

```
with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('it now prints to `help.text`')
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787220/printing-all-output-from-sklearn-gridsearchcv-to-file) solution (that is also referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325019/how-to-output-to-the-console-and-file/11325249#11325249) solution) also didn't work:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush() # If you want the output to be visible immediately
    def flush(self) :
    for f in self.files:
        f.flush()
```

And tried this [monkey-patch](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/190) as the author called it, but is also just saved the "Parallel" lines.

(Just to emphasize, the codes above are just a glimpse of the proposed solutions, when I tried them, I took all relevant code).

Is there a way to save **ALL** output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this using `sys` library or others.
Instead, I suggest the following approach where we redirect stdout and stderr properly.

Suppose you have a script like this:

**test.py**

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression()
params = {"C": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 2, 3]}
grid = GridSearchCV(model, params, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
X = np.random.randn(100, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)

grid.fit(X, y)
```

Then run it with:

```sh
python test.py > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Then you will have both "Parallel" and "CV" lines in `logfile.txt`:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    1.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  11 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s remaining:    2.9s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  15 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s remaining:    1.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  19 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s remaining:    1.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  23 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s remaining:    0.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  27 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s remaining:    0.2s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  30 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.7s finished
[CV] C=0.001 .........................................................
[CV] ............................. C=0.001, score=0.500, total=   0.0s
[CV] C=0.1 ...........................................................
[CV] ............................... C=0.1, score=0.450, total=   0.0s
[CV] C=0.1 ...........................................................
[CV] ............................... C=0.1, score=0.550, total=   0.0s
[CV] C=1 .............................................................
[CV] ................................. C=1, score=0.550, total=   0.0s
[CV] C=1 .............................................................
[CV] ................................. C=1, score=0.500, total=   0.0s
[CV] C=2 .............................................................
...
```

### Details

The "[CV]" lines are produced by `print` statement
([Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L567)).
This is written to stdout.

And "Parallel" lines are produced by loggers ([Source](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/logger.py)).
This is written to stderr.

`> logfile.txt 2>&1` is a trick to redirect both stdout and stderr to a same file ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file)).
As a result, both messages are written to a same file.

Comment: "python test.py > logfile.txt 2>&1" which is what I would have expected to work, unfortunately does not, at least on Mac OS (it's how I ended up here). I must say it's pretty bad behaviour for a library to break output redirection in this way.