# Python-Classifier-Xgboost - show cv information to long time after finish script

Tags: python, classification, stdout, xgboost, cross-validation

I have a code

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("cv.log","w")
sys.stdout = log_file

import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=2000)

params_str_dict = {"xgb__n_estimators": [10, 30], "xgb__max_depth": [50], "xgb__learning_rate": [0.5, 1], "xgb__objective": ["binary:logistic"]}

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("xgb", xgb.XGBClassifier())])
model_GS = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    param_grid=params_str_dict,
    n_jobs=-1,
    cv=3,
    verbose=3,
).fit(X_train, y_train)

sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```

When script has ended - in file i see

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 12 fits
```

However, after 2 minutes, information about the cv show in the visual output. I think that's why it's not save to the file (it comes too late)

```
[CV 1/3] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.964 total time=   0.1s
[CV 2/3] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.951 total time=   0.1s
[CV 3/3] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.961 total time=   0.1s
[CV 1/3] END xgb__learning_rate=1, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.973 total time=   0.1s
```

I use Visual Studio Code with Jupyter Kernel but in Python is the same problem.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480721/redirect-gridsearchcv-or-any-other-sklearn-object-output-to-file