# Catch sklearn joblib output to python logging

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib, python-logging

When using sklearn, I want to see the output. Therefore, I use `verbose` when available.

Generally, I want timestamps, process ids etc, so I use the python `logging` module when I can.
Getting sklearn output to the `logging` module has been done before, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803365

However, I want to run in parallell, and joblib also use `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` directly. Therefore, my attempt (see below) does not work.

```py
import logging
import sys
import contextlib

class LogAdapter:
    def __init__(self,level,logger) -> None:
        if level == 'INFO':
            self.report = logger.info
        elif level == 'ERROR':
            self.report = logger.error

    def write(self,msg):
        stripped = msg.rstrip()
        if len(stripped) > 0:
            self.report(stripped)

    def flush(self):
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_to_log(logger):
    originals = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = LogAdapter(level='INFO',logger=logger)
    sys.stderr = LogAdapter(level='ERROR',logger=logger)
    yield
    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = originals


def test_case():
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(process)d | %(asctime)s | %(name)14s | %(levelname)7s | %(message)s",
    )

    for backend_name in ['loky','threading']:
        logger.info(f"Testing backend {backend_name}")
        with parallel_backend(backend_name),redirect_to_log(logger):
            clf = RandomForestClassifier(2, verbose=4)
            X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
            Y = [0, 1]
            clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_case()
```

I get output

```py
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:16,938 |       __main__ |    INFO | Testing backend loky
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:16,951 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
building tree 1 of 2
building tree 2 of 2
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,923 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    1.9s remaining:    0.0s
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,923 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    1.9s finished
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,924 |       __main__ |    INFO | Testing backend threading
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,925 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,932 |       __main__ |    INFO | building tree 1 of 2
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,932 |       __main__ |    INFO | building tree 2 of 2
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,934 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
19320 | 2022-11-30 17:49:18,934 |       __main__ |   ERROR | [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
```

As you can see, it works nicely with the `threading` backend, but not with the `loky` backend. Loky is for multiprocessing, and the context manager of mine only catch `stdout` and `stderr` in the main process. How do I capture stdout of child processes and put them into standard python logging?

If it was a plain python subprocess call, I could catch the IO by providing pipes as in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/redirecting-subprocesses-output-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-logging-module

Others have tried and failed before me with loky, I realize. One option is to make sure a "setup logging" call is attached to each job pushed via joblib. That could work, but sklearn does not expose that level of detail, by what I know. See e.g. https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/1017

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a workaround using the `dask` backend instead. I define a worker plugin that essentially is my contextmanager

```
import dask.distributed
class LogPlugin(dask.distributed.WorkerPlugin):
    name = "LoggerRedirector"

    def setup(self, worker: dask.distributed.Worker):
        self.originals = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
        init_logging()
        sys.stdout = LogAdapter(level='INFO',logger=logging.getLogger(__name__))
        sys.stderr = LogAdapter(level='ERROR',logger=logging.getLogger(__name__))

    def teardown(self, worker: dask.distributed.Worker):
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = self.originals
```

and then register it in a dask backend

```
client = dask.distributed.Client()
client.register_worker_plugin(LogPlugin())
```

I can now get the desired output with multiprocessing.

It is an acceptable solution, but somewhat annoying, as dask has larger overhead than loky, and imposes a new dependency for me.

The new full code is:

```py
import logging
import sys
import contextlib

class LogAdapter:
    def __init__(self,level,logger) -> None:
        if level == 'INFO':
            self.report = logger.info
        elif level == 'ERROR':
            self.report = logger.error

    def write(self,msg):
        stripped = msg.rstrip()
        if len(stripped) > 0:
            self.report(stripped)

    def flush(self):
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_to_log(logger):
    originals = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = LogAdapter(level='INFO',logger=logger)
    sys.stderr = LogAdapter(level='ERROR',logger=logger)
    yield
    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = originals

def init_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(process)d | %(asctime)s | %(name)14s | %(levelname)7s | %(message)s",
    )

import dask.distributed
class LogPlugin(dask.distributed.WorkerPlugin):
    name = "LoggerRedirector"

    def setup(self, worker: dask.distributed.Worker):
        self.originals = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
        init_logging()
        sys.stdout = LogAdapter(level='INFO',logger=logging.getLogger(__name__))
        sys.stderr = LogAdapter(level='ERROR',logger=logging.getLogger(__name__))

    def teardown(self, worker: dask.distributed.Worker):
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = self.originals

def test_case():
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend
    client = dask.distributed.Client()
    client.register_worker_plugin(LogPlugin())
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    init_logging()
    for backend_name in ['loky','threading','dask']:
        logger.info(f"Testing backend {backend_name}")
        with parallel_backend(backend_name),redirect_to_log(logger):
            clf = RandomForestClassifier(2, verbose=4)
            X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
            Y = [0, 1]
            clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_case()
```

Comment: I won't accept this as an answer, since it shifts to dask. I post it more as a "this is a maybe useful non-answer that anyone might want...."

Comment: I wrote a big more in my personal blog https://el-hult.github.io/2022/11/30/sklearn-logging.html in a style that might be interesting, but don't fit with the SO format.